# Spring Boot: How can I convert Autocad to GeoJSON?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, npm, npm-install, geojson

I'm new to Autocad, and Spring boot. I need to convert Autocad (dxf/dwg) file to geoJSON using spring boot or angular. How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39262958

Comment: Can we do it  programmatically is it possible without use Command prompt???